# Explicit presentation of a group

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

$$\langle G\mid \{abc\mid a,b,c \in G, abc = 1\}\rangle$$ is a presentation of $G$.

Why did we specifically choose the relations to be of length 3?

(Why not something like $\{ab\mid a,b \in G, ab = 1\}$ or $\{abcd\mid a,b,c,d \in G,abcd = 1 \}$?)

(This example appears in https://www.math.ucla.edu/~azhou/notes/1/210ABC/notes.pdf, page 34)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the notation confusing at first, hence my earlier comment, but once I saw the context, now I see the point.

The authors mean that any group $G$ has a presentation in which the set of generators is the whole set $G$, and the relations correspond to all the products. That is, for all $a, b \in G$, you write a relation $a b c = 1$, where $c = (a b)^{-1}$.

Comment: It is an interesting exercise to see what $H = \langle  G \mid \{ a, b \in G, a b = 1 \} \rangle$ is, for an arbitrary group $G$. Write $G$ as a disjoint union $I \cup X \cup Y$, where $I = \{ g \in G \mid g^{2} = 1\}$, and $X, Y$ are chosen so that $Y = \{ x^{-1} \mid x \in X \}$. Then if I am not mistaken, $H$ is the free group on $I \cup X$.